# How does urllib3 determine which TLS extensions to use?

Tags: python, ssl, httpclient, tls1.2, urllib3

I'd like to modify the Extensions that I send in the client Hello packet with python.
I've had a read of most of the source code found on GitHub for urllib3 but I still don't know how it determines which TLS extensions to use.
I am aware that it will be quite low level and the creators of urllib3 may just import another package to do this for them. If this is the case, which package do they use?
If not, how is this determined?
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What does urllib3 do? How is it related to C?

Comment: urllib3 is used to make http requests within python, it gives you more control than the requests library which is more popular than urllib3 because it is much easier to use. It is related to c because you cannot gain access to to extensions, elliptic curves etc. in python so c code has to be wrapped in python code in order to gain access to these fields within the client hello packet.
I realised i didn't actually tag python in this so i'll remove the c tag and replace it with python to avoid any further confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTPS support in `urllib3` uses the `ssl` package which uses the openssl C-library. `ssl` does not provide any way to directly fiddle with the TLS extension except for setting the hostname in the TLS handshake (i.e. `server_name` extension aka SNI).